# Explaining the eigenvariable condition in sequent calculus

Tags: logic, quantifiers, proof-theory, sequent-calculus

In sequent calculus LK, the right quantifier rule is
$$
\dfrac{\Gamma\vdash[y\backslash x]A, \Delta}{\Gamma\vdash\forall xA, \Delta}\forall\text{R}
$$
where $y$, the eigenvariable, cannot occur free in any lower sequent (the eigenvariable condition).

I don't understand why the eigenvariable, $y$, can never occur free in lower sequents. I see why the eigenvariable condition is necessary immediately after the application of the rule but not in lower sequents. Take for example the following partial deduction:
$$
\dfrac{\dfrac{\Gamma\vdash A(x)}{\Gamma\vdash\forall xA(x)}\forall \text{R}\quad\Delta\vdash B(x)}{\Gamma, \Delta\vdash\forall xA(x)\wedge B(x)}\wedge\text{R}
$$
where $x$ only occurs in $A$ and $B$.

To me it seems that there's nothing logically wrong with this partial deduction (reading top-down) even though, according to the eigenvariable condition, this is invalid. It seems that the eigenvariable condition only needs to hold up until the next fork in the deduction. What am I missing here?

Comment: I've never heard it phrased that it can't occur free in *any* lower sequent. Only that it can't occur free in the lower sequent of the $\forall \mathrm{R}$ step (this is how Takeuti, for instance, phrases it).

Comment: @MaliceVidrine I'm quoting wikipedia: "Restrictions: In the rules $(\forall R)$ and $(\exists L)$, the variable $y$ must not occur free anywhere in the respective lower sequents." https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequent_calculus

Comment: you should give a reference for where you are seeing this rule. The form I’m used to seeing is that the eigenvariable just must not occur in the lower sequent of the derivation, not that it can’t occur anywhere lower in the proof. At the same time it’s pretty clear that this additional restriction won’t ruin anything since we can always just rename free variables and get a derivation with the same content that satisfies it.

Comment: @KainoaB The lower sequent is the one on the bottom of the inference line, not anything lower in the tree. The only reason they pluralize there is that they are referring to two rules.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen Okay that makes more sense, I guess I just read it incorrectly.